# css question - themeing button

Tags: css, button, themes

i've made a little button widget which is styled with some gfx.
my css class for that button is like:

```
div.tButton
{
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(/button/button.png);
}
...
```

that .css also has classes for hover, click and disabled button-state.

what i wanna do is create different button themes (color,size ..) which use one universal .css file and just additions for height and background-image - so i don't have to create a whole css file for each theme.

how could this be done?

eg. for the html markup i've tried something like

```
<div class=tButton btn40>mybutton</div>
```

where btn40 whould be a .css class with different height + background-image, but doesn't work.

any idea if this is possible?

thanks

Comment: Add quotes: <div class="tButton btn40">mybutton</div>

Comment: i've tried but for some reason the btn40 class gets truncated and it's still just class="tButton" (when checking in firebug) dunno why ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the `!important` at the end of the style attribute will force this class's style attribute to override all others.  This will allow you to define the following as the default:

```
<div class="tButton">mybutton</div>
```

and will allow you to define customizations like this

```
<div class="tButton btn40">mybutton</div>
<div class="tButton btn30">mybutton</div>
```

Here is how you would set up the style.

```
div.tButton
{
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(/button/button.png);
}

.btn40
{
   height:30px !important;
   background-image:url('/button/btn40.png') !important
}


.btn30
{
   height:50px !important;
   background-image:url('/button/btn30.png') !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.tButton {
            height:20px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-color: red;
            width: 80px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .btn40 {
           height:30px !important;
           background-color: green !important;
           margin-bottom: 20px !important;
           margin-top: 20px !important;
           width: 120px !important;
           line-height: 30px;
        }
        .btn30 {
           height:50px !important;
           background-color: blue !important;
           width: 150px !important;
           line-height: 45px;
        }

<div class="tButton">mybutton</div> 
<div class="tButton btn40">mybutton</div>
<div class="tButton btn30">mybutton</div>
```